# Issue with JSP on Tomcat 7: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat

I'm trying to run a `JSP` project but I'm getting lots of error on build.

I'm using  `JRE version 1.8.0.112` and the `Tomcat 7`, here is the error log:

```
Nov 15, 2016 11:15:59 AM org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler$1 findType
SEVERE: Compilation error
org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.classfmt.ClassFormatException
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.classfmt.ClassFileReader.<init>(ClassFileReader.java:372)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler$1.findType(JDTCompiler.java:220)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler$1.findType(JDTCompiler.java:176)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.LookupEnvironment.askForType(LookupEnvironment.java:103)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.UnresolvedReferenceBinding.resolve(UnresolvedReferenceBinding.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.BinaryTypeBinding.resolveType(BinaryTypeBinding.java:122)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.PackageBinding.getTypeOrPackage(PackageBinding.java:168)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.Scope.getType(Scope.java:2397)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.TypeDeclaration.resolve(TypeDeclaration.java:1005)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.TypeDeclaration.resolve(TypeDeclaration.java:1235)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.CompilationUnitDeclaration.resolve(CompilationUnitDeclaration.java:540)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.process(Compiler.java:759)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:464)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:447)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:374)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:352)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:339)
    at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:594)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:344)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:391)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:33


SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: 1 in the generated java file
The type java.io.ObjectInputStream cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class filesorg.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:391)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a known issue with Tomcat 7 + JRE/JDK 8 past update 91, so as a workaround you can:

- Try downgrading your JRE/JDK to 7 **or**
- Try upgrading your Tomcat to 8

Comment: Thanks a lot. I struggled with this problem for almost 2 days. And after downgrading JDK to pre-91 update, it all worked.